# Bitly shortened url different between v3 and v4 api call using the same long url

Tags: rest, api, migration, migrate, bit.ly

We want to migrate our integration with bitly from v 3 to v4, and during our tests we noticed that the returned shortened url is not same comparing the v3 and v4 returned lin, even if we send the same long url as a parameter value.

As there is a max limit for the number of urls in our contract with bitly, will the long url shortened url in v4 be counted as a new one even if it was already sent and registered in v3?

Also, will the shortened urls in v3 (before the migration) will they still work after mai 1st 2020 (when v3 will no longer be available)?